# Enable button when group of textfields are completed

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols, qtquickcontrols2

I want to enable one button when, and only when, a group of text fields are filled and validated with RegExp. If you think in a web register form, I need the same behaviour in QML application. Of course, **I know that it is possible using JS** code but my goal is not to use it and do this with an elegant way, using only declarative qml code. Any ideas about?

This is an example:

```
Label {
    text: qsTr('First name')
}

TextField {
    id: firstNameTextField
}

Label {
    text: qsTr('Last name')
}

TextField {
    id: lastNameTextField
}

Label {
    text: qsTr('email')
}

// Username
TextField {
    id: emailTextField
    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter email")
    smooth: true
    validator: RegExpValidator{ regExp: /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i }
}

Label {
    text: qsTr('Password')
}

TextField {
    id: passwordTextField
}

Label {
    text: qsTr('Re-Password')
}

TextField {
    id: rePasswordTextField
}
Button {
    id:button
    enabled: // all text fields completed and validated
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the same solution coded in a declarative fashion:

```
Row {
    TextField {
        id: field1
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter number 1")
        validator: IntValidator {bottom: 1; top: 9;}
    }
    TextField {
        id: field2
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter number 2")
        validator: IntValidator {bottom: 11; top: 19;}
    }
    Button {
        id: btn
        text: "Send"
        enabled: field1.acceptableInput && field2.acceptableInput
    }
}
```

From the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#acceptableInput-prop):

> acceptableInput  - Returns true if the text field contains acceptable
>   text. If a validator or input mask was set, this property will return
>   true if the current text satisfies the validator or mask as a final
>   string

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and dirty way of doing it.
Use the boolean properties as intermediate for enabling the button as below

```
Item{
property bool isNameFieldValid : false
property bool isAgeFieldValid : false

TextField {
    id: name
    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter name")
    validator:  RegExpValidator{regExp:"valid JS regEx"}
    onAccepted:isNameFieldValid=true
 }
TextField {
    id: age
    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter name")
    validator:  RegExpValidator{regExp:/[0-9A-F]+/}
    onAccepted:isAgeFieldValid=true
 }
Button{
 id:confirmButton
  enable:isNameFieldValid && isAgeFieldValid
 }
}
```

But the only thing is, field gets validated only when the user clicks Enter key on Keyboard/keypad.

Comment: Thanks, as you say, this is a dirty way. :) Maybe it is not possible to do using QML.